# Safari doesn't send `referer` header

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, webkit, http-referer

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
var clk = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
clk.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(clk);
```

When use this method, the `http_referer` doesn't send. Can you help me please.

(method simulate `ctrl+click` to the link)

Answer (score 3):

Please try to add this to your

```
    <meta name="referrer" content="always">
```

This should fix it for desktop Safari. It may not fix it for ios safari. You may want to use content of origin.

A good explanation:
http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html