# Make it so url can only be accessed through redirect

Tags: django, redirect, django-templates, django-urls

I am redirecting my users from a paypal payment to the register.html so that you can only register once you have paid the subscription.

How do I make it so that this redirect is the only way to access the page and not simply by putting mysite.com/register in the browser?

I have pages where login is required but obviously this will be before a user has registered so cannot do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for the requirement posted in OP, you might be interested in using `HTTP_REFERER` available in [HttpRequest.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) to tell you from where the user is redirected from.

Here is a sample view on how you can implement it in django

```
def your_view(request):
    print(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    if request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER') == 'whatever url of paypal you want to allow':
        some_context = {}
        return render(request, 'yourhtml.html', some_context)
    return redirect('/') # it can be redirected to anywhere if user is not intended audience
```

Thereby it will only show this view to the user coming from url set by you in the if condition

**Note: I would not say it is secure but it will do the trick**

To make it secure i would suggest you to setup a short lived temperory token such as jwt or something for user validation(if possible). I am not having much idea about paypal so wouldn't say much.

Comment: So with Paypal a unique checkout token is added on to the url with each transaction. How could I make it so that the referer accepts all coming from redirects coming from https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ ?

Comment: As of my knowledge it don't think there is any way of getting complete url when referer is not your domain but is possible inside the website. Here, i think you need to configure auto redirect url to redirect to `https://www.yourdomain.com/register?checkout-token=yourtoken` in paypal.

Comment: I will try to update the complete code in some time, might need to check paypal documentation.  Till then this might be helpful https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/customize-flow/

Comment: I have set this up and it is all working on Google Chrome and not Safari, is there any reason for this?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/20716439/10140011, i can't confirm it as i don't use safari.

Answer (score 3):

You can add payment id to your url, for example:
mysite.com/register/<payment_id>
and then check if the payment id is confirmed or not, if is completed you can display register form or redirect if payment is wrong